# copyfile is copying into VirtualStore folder?

Tags: winapi, windows-vista, file-copying, virtualstore

I have created one application on Vista, that is running with admin privileges.

I am trying to copy one file to `ProgramData\Application\` folder.

But instead to copying there its copying at location `c:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\ProgramData\Application\`

I dont want this file to get copied into Virtul store.

Any suggestion , how can I overcome this issue?

I am using `CopyFile` API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a [Vista manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx) to your application to disable the FS virtualization

Comment: So this is COM exe.Earlier I was calling this COM API from low privilege process and I was elevating the privileges of EXE while launching exe. If I add manifest, I am not able to launch the com server.

Comment: I did not say you had to choose requireAdministrator, just using asInvoker will also turn off the compatibility stuff